# How to replace Indeterminate with NaN in a list and ignore it?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, replacement

Say I have a list of values and one returns Indeterminate. Is there a way to replace it with say NaN and then keep the rest of the list?

Comment: Do you want literally the symbol `NaN`? How is that better than having `Indeterminate`? Maybe you can tell us what you're trying to achieve and how `Indeterminate` is interfering with that.

Comment: By "ignore it" do you mean remove it? In that case, `DeleteCases[<your list>, Indeterminate]`

Answer (score 1):

How you want to do this probably depends on what you want to do with the list later. In Mathematica, Indeterminate is a kind of NaN. But if the intent is to remove the offending value, you can do something like this:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 0/0, 4, 5, 6};
blist = list /. Indeterminate -> Nothing
```

Now blist is {1,2,3,4,5,6}